# how to install mapbox in android studio properly? activity not found after installing the dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox

i have followed a tutorial about MapBox , when i want to install any dependencies of any mapbox , no dependency of any tutorial works with me , here the last ones i tried , and the error in this time is
Default activity not found

//gradle :app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.miniprojetandroid"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}




dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //ROOM
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0'

    //mapbox
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v7:0.7.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-geocoder:1.0.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-markerview-v7:0.2.0'




    //Material
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'


    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

//gradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
        //maven { url "https//jitpack.io" }
       // maven { url "https//dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Why no mapbox tutorial or dependencies works with me ? and why in my last try an error of default activity not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to go with the official documentation to install Mapbox SDKs. The one you are using is definitely outdated by years.

Mapbox has changed the way its libraries can get downloaded. To access the maven repo to download the SDK you now need to configure access credentials and add them to the module level build.gradle:

```js
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
      authentication {
          basic(BasicAuthentication)
      }
      credentials {
        // Do not change the username below.
        // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
          username = 'mapbox'
          // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
          password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please follow this documentation:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/